# Turn off auto restart on android when remove screen?

Tags: android, android-10.0, custom-rom, razorpay-andoid-sdk

I am editing Android 10 ROM to run on phones without a screen. However, when I remove the screen, the phone automatically restarts. How can I disable this feature?

"I have researched many forums, but there is no solution."